# Captcha image to text in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

I am writing a script intended to read a captcha from a site and output a text.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'PATH\tesseract.exe'
original = Image.open("o-captcha.jpeg")
bw = original.convert("L") 
bw.save("bw-captcha.png")
```

I have converted to the image in black and white which I think already give a nice outline of the text. However, I could not get the text from `pytesseract.pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('bw-captcha.png'), lang='eng')`

Is it due to low resolution of image? (`96dpi 55x20`)

When I upload this site (https://www.prepostseo.com/image-to-text), it can be easily recognized.

How can I achieve the result? Thanks for your help.

Original Captcha:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMntj.jpg)

B & W Captcha:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA6kE.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [what are you asking], and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and provide a [mre].